# Devise + Rspec: not signed in user passing through authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

In my tests, despite not getting user signed in , tests get through `before_filter: authenticate_user!` to parts of the API it should not have access to.

Adding some print out to my setup:

```
class ClubsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :derp, only: [:create]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!,:authorize_user, :derp, only: [:update, :destroy, :admins, :add_admin, :delete_admin]

  def derp
    puts "derp: #{user_signed_in?}"
  end

  def authorize_user
    user = current_user
    club = Club.find(params[:id])
    head :unauathorized unless ClubAdmin.exists?(club_id: club.id, user_id: user.id)
  end
```

Shows that during tests all `derp`'s are true, but

```
def create
    puts "create: #{user_signed_in?}"
    @club = Club.new(params.require(:club).permit(:name, :city, :description))
    @club.creator = current_user
    @club.save
```

prints one `create: false`.

This issue is probably cause of most fails in my tests.

Tests code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ClubsController do
  render_views

  def prepare_user(authenticated = false, authorized = false, club_id = nil)
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]

    if authenticated
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      sign_in user
      ClubAdmin.create(club_id: club_id, user_id: user.id) if authorized
    end
  end

  def prepare_create
    xhr :post, :create, format: :json, club: {
      name: "CreatedClub",
      city: "CreativeCity",
      description: "Sooo creative"
    }
  end

  describe "create" do
    context "when the user is not authenticated" do
      before do
        prepare_user
        prepare_create
      end
      puts "cre un #{User.all} "
      it{expect(response.status).to eq(401)}
    end

    context "when the user is authenticated" do
      before do
        prepare_user(true, false)
        prepare_create
      end

      puts "cre au #{User.all} "
      it {expect(response.status).to eq(201)}
      it {expect(Club.last.name).to eq("CreatedClub")}
      it {expect(Club.last.city).to eq("CreativeCity")}
      it {expect(Club.last.description).to eq("Sooo creative")}
    end
  end
```

To gather it all up: what should I do to prevent signed_in state from propagating between tests or how can make `authenticate_user!` filter out tests with not signed in user?

The full project in current state can be found [here](https://github.com/morynicz/Ippon/tree/9046376abccf9be30d303febfe287a8619110ea6)

========================== EDIT =======================

@Max's solution solved almost all the issues besides `create` method getting accessed when user is not authenticated. This time 'derp log' is returning false

Current state of code [here](https://github.com/morynicz/Ippon/tree/8f1d9aac46e03f8b244a1066fdd5a8d7fbf4b826)

Comment: Since Devise is using sessions to maintain the "current_user" in the background you could probably get away with adding a "reset_session" statement in the controller action your tests start with before logging in which would set the current_user back to nil.

Comment: @bkunzi01 it does'nt really work that way with controller specs since they fake the whole request and the rack layer where Warden lives. Instead you want to use `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` and the sign_out method which stubs Warden.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets setup some shared authentication helpers [in a module](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) so that we don't have to duplicate it:

```
# spec/support/controller_auth_helper
module ControllerAuthHelpers
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    let(:current_user) { FactortGirl.create(:user) }
    before do |ex|
      sign_out :user # resets any residual state
      if ex.metadata[:authenticated]
        sign_in current_user
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

What does is setup up a `before` block to reset any lingering state by using `sign_out :user`.

It also lets you sign in a user simply by adding metadata to the example or group:

```
context "when logged in", authenticated: true do
  # ...
end

it "allows a known user", authenticated: true do
  get :something
  expect(response).to have_http_status :ok
end
```

It uses [a lazy loading `let` variable](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-4/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) called `current_user` which you can override at any time.

```
let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, cool: true) }
```

Include them in your `spec/spec_helper.rb` (`rails_helper` for later versions of RSpec).

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include ControllerAuthHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

---

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ClubsController do
  # if you need render_views you should be using a request spec instead!
  render_views 

  describe "POST :create" do
    let(:attributes) { { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:club) } }
    let(:action) do
        xhr :post, :create, format: :json, club: attributes
    end

    context "when the user is not authenticated" do
      it "does not create a club" do
        expect {
          action
        }.to_not change(Club, :count)
      end      

      it "denies access" do
        action
        expect(response).to have_http_status :unauthorized
      end
    end

    context "when the user is authenticated", authenticated: true do
      context "with invalid attributes" do

        let(:attributes) do
          {
             name: '',
             city: ''
          }
        end

        it "does not create a club" do
          expect {
            action
          }.to_not change(Club, :count)
        end      

        it "returns the correct status" do
          action
          expect(response).to have_http_status :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
      context "with valid attributes" do
        it "creates a club" do
          expect {
            action
          }.to change(Club, :count).by(1)
        end      

        it "returns the correct status" do
          action
          expect(response).to be_successful 
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that you are using a really old version (2.99) of `rspec-rails` in your project. The current version is 3.4.

Comment: Almost all fixed besides create, I edited the question. Also: thanks for pointing out that I'm using old versions.

Comment: Added an example of how I would test it.

Comment: On a side note - don't use `it {expect(Club.last.city).to eq("CreativeCity")}` without a message. It tells you nothing about the behavior you are testing and will give an extremely cryptic failure message. You can use the `rspec-its` gem together with `subject` if you want to write really succint tests. Use it with care though.